# Large weights in NN

Tags: machine-learning

My NN when training seems to produce weights that are very large. Is it okay if weights in a neural network have values greater than 1 or less than -1?

Furthermore, the extremely large weights tend to be in the connections between the input and first hidden layer. For example, the input-hidden layer weights look something like this:

```
-12.728901995585,-13.2337212413569,5.73922593605989,-5.12803672380726......
```

Whereas the hidden-output weights look more like:

```
-0.00434217225630834,0.130458439630824,0.153923956195796,0.59407334088441
```

The NN functions fine, however the large weights are concerning as usually I seem them being between -1 and 1. Are larger weights okay?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you initializing them to? What is your data normalized to?

Comment: As of now, they are initialized to a value between -0.7 and 0.7. The network is simulating a full-adder so the data will either be a 0 or 1. I'm using a sigmoid function to keep the data between those values. I know that kind of scenario might lead to over-fitting but this is mainly for experimentation.

Comment: Does any kind of normalization help at all?

Comment: If I normalise the weights with a function the network tends to not function.

Answer (score 0):

According to this example https://mattmazur.com/2015/03/17/a-step-by-step-backpropagation-example/ your NN's weights between input and hidden layers may seem to be off the usual (assuming feed forward NNs). Towards the end of the given example you will see how smaller the changes are generated through back-propagation.

But depending on the training iteration count and NN architecture it is possible to have large weights too. Also larger weights mean the preceding neuron has more effect than the following neuron on NN's decision.

In general NN's interior values are difficult to understand. If your NN does the job, I guess it's OK to have large weights between some layers.

I am unfortunately not very proficient on the subject. So corrections and their explanations are welcome if any. I am looking forward to learn from experts.

Comment: Mhm, yeah all those weights are much smaller. I think I'll ignore it for now though and see if it persists when I try using the network for other tasks.

Comment: @AlexMcKinney 2 years ago I wanted to learn about back-propagation, that was the only example I could find on how it actually works with numbers. Glad you liked it.

Comment: I used 'Make your own Neural Network' by Tariq Rashid. He explains it quite well and an implementation in Python although aimed at beginners.

Comment: @AlexMcKinney Thank you for the reference, the title looks promising, will definitely check it.

Comment: If you've been doing it for two years you've probably not going to learn much new, but it was useful for myself as I am new to this :)